# Scala//Squeryl/Play Retrieve multiple values from the same param

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I have the following url : `http://localhost/api/books/?bookId=21&bookId=62?authorId=2`

But how i can retrieve all the bookId values with Scala  ?

I'm using the PlayFrameWork as the WebServer, so here's my code :

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) }

System.out.print(params.get("bookId"));
```

**params.get("bookId")** only get the last value in the bookId params. e-g : **62**.

How can i retrieve all my bookId params ? Once i know how, i will be able to convert them into Integers.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a List in Play framework web service parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814866/have-a-list-in-play-framework-web-service-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to update your `routes` file, Play! can extract and transform duplicate Keys into an array for you:

```
GET    /api/books    controllers.Books.show(bookId: List[Int], authorId: Id)
```

will provide you with the parameter `bookId: List[Int]` to use in your call definition `def show(bookId: List[Int], authorId: Int)`

** **UPDATE** **

From the Play spec, it should:

> "support several query string values for a parameter"

`request.queryString` returns a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`

The problem is you're transforming that into a `Map[String, String]` with:

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) }
```

`v(0)` takes the first occurrence of each parameter

Just use the queryString `Map` directly: for the request `/api/books/?bookId=21&bookId=62?authorId=2` `request.queryString.get("bookId")` will return a  `Option[Seq[String]]` of all the bookId values which you can iterate over:

```
request.queryString.get("bookId").map { bookIds: Seq[String] => *do something with book ids here * }
```

Comment: There's away to avoid changing the routes and just retrieve the values from the string params ? Like it's the case with one param ? e-g authorId ? Because i will use the BookId params to fetch in a database using the IN clause. Thanks

Comment: Can i have only Map[String, Seq[String]] then and use it when i don't have an array also ? eg : val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v } and then get the values this way : params.get('bookId') and params.get('authorId') ?  Cause at the end i want to have something like this : (a.authorId === params.get("authorId").?) and (params.get("bookId").map(bookIds: Seq[String] => b.bookId in bookIds).getOrElse(1 === 1).inhibitWhen(false))

Comment: That doesn't look like scala -- is this a SQL DSL? Maybe you could post as a new question, ideally (if i'm following) what you have is your own repository interface layer and you could query for an author and a List of bookIds, and that List could be of length 1+

Comment: I'm using Scala and Squeryl. The goal is to get the values of authorId and BookId and fetch them in the Database : where (a.authorId === params.get("authorId").?) and (params.get("bookId").map(b => b.bookIds in MyListofBookIds))) –