# Scala/Play/Squeryl Retrieve multiple params

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I have the following url : `http://localhost/api/books/?bookId=21&bookId=62?authorId=2`

I want to retrieve all the bookId values with Scala and then use Squeryl to do a fetch in a the database.

I'm using the PlayFrameWork as the WebServer, so here's my code :

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) } // Retrieve only one the first occurence of a param
```

So **params.get("bookId")** will only get the last value in the bookId params. e-g : **62**.

To retrieve all my bookId params i tried this : 
 `val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v }` so i can get a Seq[String], but what about the authorId which is not a Seq[String]? .

At the end i want to fetch the bookIds and authorId in my DB using Squeryl :

```
(a.author_id === params.get("authorId").?) and
(params.get("bookId").map(bookIds: Seq[String] => b.bookId in bookIds))
```

In my controller i get the params and open the DB connection :

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) }

DB.withTransaction() { where(Library.whereHelper(params)}
```

In my model i use the queries :

```
def whereHelper(params : Map[String,String]) = {

 (a.author_id === params.get("authorId").?) and
 (params.get("bookId").map{bookIds: Seq[String] => b.bookId in bookIds})
}
```

Since bookIds is a list, i need to use the Seq[String]. There's a way to use request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v } for  both a string (authorId) and a list of strings (bookIds) ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `params.get("authorId")`? If there a single value, you will get a `Seq` with only one value, (that can be turned into `Option[String]` using `.headOption`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a List in Play framework web service parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814866/have-a-list-in-play-framework-web-service-parameters)

Comment: It's not a duplicate since i don't want to change the routes

Comment: What do you want to query for? Could you describe it because I don't understand why you would want to query for two bookIds and one authorId. Do you want to search for authors or books?

Comment: Are the multiple BookIds `OR` or `AND`. That's what I want to know.

Comment: I want to search for both ! if param authorId is not empty, i search for authorId, if param booksId is not empty, i search for booksId, if authorId and booksId are not empty, i search for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand what you are trying to do, you want to know how to get the parameters from `queryString`. This is pretty simple and you can do the following at your controller:

```
def myAction = Action { request =>
    // get all the values from parameter named bookId and 
    // transforming it to Long. Maybe you don't want the map
    // and then you can just remove it.
    val bookIds: Seq[Long] = request.queryString("bookId").map(_.toLong)

    // Notice that now I'm using getQueryString which is a helper
    // method to access a queryString parameter. It returns an
    // Option[String] which we are mapping to a Option[Long].
    // Again, if you don't need the mapping, just remove it.
    val authorId: Option[Long] = request.getQueryString("authorId").map(_.toLong)

    DB.withTransaction() { where(Library.whereHelper(authorId, bookIds) }

    // Do something with the result
}
```

At your model you will have:

```
def whereHelper(authorId: Option[Long], booksId: List[Long]) = authorId match {
  case Some(author_id) =>
      (a.author_id === author_id) and
      (b.bookId in bookIds)
  case None =>
      (b.bookId in bookIds)
}
```

I've left explicit types to help you understand what is happen. Now, since you have both values, you can just use the values at your query.

---

### Edit after chat:

But, since you want to receive a `params: Map[String, Seq[String]]` at your models and is just having problems about how to get the `authorId`, here is what you can do:

```
def whereHelper(params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = {
  // Here I'm being defensive to the fact that maybe there is no
  // "booksIds" key at the map. So, if there is not, an Seq.empty
  // will be returned. map method will run only if there is something
  // at the Seq.
  val booksIds = params.getOrElse("booksIds", Seq.empty).map(_.toLong)

  // The same defensive approach is being used here, and also getting
  // the head as an Option, so if the Seq is empty, a None will be 
  // returned. Again, the map will be executed only if the Option
  // is a Some, returning another Some with the value as a Long.
  val authorId = params.getOrElse("authorId", Seq.empty).headOption
  authorId.map(_.toLong) match {
    case Some(author_id) =>
      (a.author_id === author_id) and
      (b.bookId in booksIds)
    case None =>
      (b.bookId in booksIds)
  }
}
```

Of course, more parameters you have, more complicated this method will be.

Comment: I want to send the values from my controller to my model. I updated my question :)

Comment: If the values are coming from a request, you will have to get them at the controller and then pass them to your model.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, see my updated question

Comment: Can i do something like this : whereHelper(params: Map[String, Seq[String]])  (a.author_id === params.getLong("author_id").?)  and  (b.bookId in params.get("books_id").?)  cause that will avoid me to pass all my params in the the whereHelper. AuthorId can me a Seq and i will need to get his first occurence

Comment: You can do something very similar, but I would advocate to have separated parameters as I show at the edited answer. Any reasons to receive a `params: Map[String, Seq[String]]` at your models instead of separated parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111257/discussion-between-user708683-and-marcospereira).

Comment: See edits after chat. Also, considering using a more typesafe code here, maybe using an `params: Map[String, Seq[Long]]` instead of a `params: Map[String, Seq[String]]`.

Comment: There's a way to just not use the cases and match?
i just wanna keep it simple and have only where clauses in the helperWhere function, eg a.author_id ===params.getOrElse("authorId", Seq.empty).headOption.?) and a.params_2 ===params.getOrElse("params_2", Seq.empty).headOption.?) and a.param_3 ===params.getOrElse("params_3", Seq.empty).headOption.?) etc.

Comment: Now i have a new param page : .page(Try(params.getOrElse("page", Seq.empty).map(_.toInt)).getOrElse(0) and i got an error now value * is not a member of Any !