# Playframework: Scala Passing List[string] to WS API with GET method

Tags: scala, playframework

In my application I need to pass a `List[String]` to WS API using the `GET` method. I tried using `withQueryString`, but I'm not able to pass the `queryString` data. How to pass list data to controller? How it process the data?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A HTTP request to a third party service or are you trying to receive more than a `List[String]` at your controller? Can you show us (maybe using [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/)) how the GET request looks like?

Comment: i need to receive List[String] in My controller Not to the Thirdparty api services

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814866/have-a-list-in-play-framework-web-service-parameters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031630/scala-play-squeryl-retrieve-multiple-params/37040324#37040324.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I deciphered the question correctly, you want to receive a `List[String]` in your controller, like:

```
GET   /route   MyController.someMethod(ids: List[String])
```

and call it from other app, via WS call, like:

```
val ids = List("1", "3", "99")
val idsTuples = ids map (id => "ids" -> id)
ws.url(url).withQueryString(idsTuples: _*).get()
```

See also [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS#Request-with-query-parameters).
You can also add more parameters before the `idsTuples: _*`, or just add `(String, String)` tuples to the `idsTuples`...

**EDIT**: I wrote the first version from my memory, which wasn't correct... :)

Comment: i already tried this but it is throwing an error in querystring statement that it requires Seq(string,string) not Seq(string,list[string])

Comment: I fixed it now, yes, you need to pass varargs of type(s) `(String, String)`, so if you have a `List[(String, String)]` you can pass it like varargs using `: _*` magic.